# AJAX call to backend PHP file and making result appear in HTML span

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an AJAX call to a PHP file that performs some date calculations. I can confirm that it works if I place a text field on the form and put the focus in it after the start and end dates are entered (i.e., if I enter 1/1/2014 and 12/31/2014, I get 260 if I tab over to my "result" field).

What I'm trying to do now is have the result show up in a span after the end date is entered. That way, the user doesn't have to tab over to a text field to see it. Here is my jQuery code to call the file and display the result in the span:

```
$(function() 
  {
  $('#result').focusin(function(event) //'result' is the name of the span
  {
      var start = $('#startDate').val();
      var end = $('#endDate').val();

     $("#endDate").on('input',function() {
     var dateRegex = /(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/gm;
     if(dateRegex.test($("#endDate").val()) ) { //Make sure date is formatted correctly  

      $.ajax(
      {
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'calcdays.php',
          data: 
          {
              startDate: start,
              endDate: end
          },
          success: function(data) 
          {       
              $('#result').html(data);
          }
      }); //End ajax
    } //End if
  }); //End regex function

      event.preventDefault();

    }); //End focusin
}); //End function
```

And here is the form setup:

```
<label for="startDate">StartDate</label>
<input type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate" />
<label for="endDate">EndDate</label>
<input type="text" name="endDate" id="endDate" />
Result: <span id="result"> </span>
```

I'm not able to make my result appear within the span. What did I miss?

Comment: you missed showing us the PHP code. It can definitely be broken or something.

Comment: also check that you have `id="result"` only once on the page. This fault is much more common than people think

Comment: Did you make sure the event `$('#result').focusin()` gets call?

Comment: in your "calcday.php" are you using `print` or `echo` to return your results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no focus events on spans I think. I think you meant

```
$('input[name="endDate"]').blur(function(event) {
```

But there is nowhere to blur out of endDate. You need to define, what does "end date is entered" mean. User press enter key? Or tab button and blurs somewhere? Or you can use keyup to check value of current end date

```
$('input[name="endDate"]').keyup(function(event) {
```

Anyway you should remove focusein part, you just bind something to event, which happens with enddate input, you can bind it right after document ready.

Comment: Working like a champ now. Thanks!